# Tracking Failure of DatabaseBackup in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SMO. I want to send email on successful backup and failed backup as well. I can easily get to know if backup is successful by  using either percent complete or Completed event handler. But how to check if the backup has been failed?

Comment: If the backup fails, it will throw a https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.smoexception.aspx  Use a try/catch around your backup code and handle the failure

Comment: @Mangist : I am using code for backup inside try block. It is not going inside catch if backup is getting failed.

Comment: I have an app that does backups and putting the backup in a try/catch will catch when the backup fails. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162127.aspx

Comment: @Mangist: Mycode is not going inside catch block when backup is unsuccessful. Please help

Comment: @Mangist : I am using SqlBackupAsync method.